# How to console.log individual req.checkBody params(errors msg) - express-Validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars, express-validator

This code working fine. It throws errors and displayed to the webpage. But now i want to pick individual errors and display to the webpage.

```
    // request.body validation
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('phone', 'Phone is required.').isMobilePhone('en-IN');
  req.checkBody('password1', 'Password is required.').isLength({min:6});
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Password not same, try again!!').equals(password1);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    console.log(req.body.params.errors);
    res.render('form', {
      errors: errors,
      isForm: true,
      register: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log('PASSED');
  }
```

What will be the code to console.log individual params of the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn on [`mapped`](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#reqvalidationerrorsmapped). That makes the `errors` array an ordinary object, so you can access the particular errors with dot syntax:

```
  var errors = req.validationErrors(true);  // note the true argument

  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors);

    res.render('form', {
      errors: errors.phone,  // ordinary object access syntax
      isForm: true,
      register: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log('PASSED');
  }
```

---

You can also do it with mapped set to false. This is the default way.

The `errors` variable is then an array, so you can access its elements like in any other array:

```
  if (errors) {
    res.render('form', {
      errors: errors[0], // only the first error
      isForm: true,
      register: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log('PASSED');
  }
```

If you want to send an element that belongs to a particular field you can use a for loop to find its location in `errors`:

```
  // request.body validation
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('phone', 'Phone is required.').isMobilePhone('en-IN');
  req.checkBody('password1', 'Password is required.').isLength({ min: 6 });
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Password not same, try again!!').equals('password1');

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    // look for phone
    let indexOfPhone = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i += 1) {
      if (errors[i].param === 'phone') indexOfPhone = i;
    }

    res.render('form', {
      errors: errors[indexOfPhone],
      isForm: true,
      register: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log('PASSED');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop to print the params when the **errors variable** has value or values dumped in it, by the **req.validationErrors()** .

```
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required.').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('phone', 'Phone is required.').isMobilePhone('enIN');
req.checkBody('password1', 'Password is required.').isLength({min:6});
req.checkBody('password2', 'Password not same, try again!!').equals(password1);

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
  // true condition : errors has values stored in it
  // printing out the params of each error using a for loop
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < errors.length;i++) 
  { 
    console.log(i," : ",errors[i]['param']); // printing out the params
  }
  res.render('form', {
  errors: errors,
  isForm: true,
  register: true
  });
} else {
  // false condition : errors is empty
  console.log('PASSED');
}
```